# Using JSOM outside sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, jsom, azure

I have a big application that uses the SP.ClientContext (JSOM).

I need to deploy it to a static web app on Azure.

How can I obtain the variable (or something similar)? I would like to avoid switching to the Graph client because of the number of requests that I'll have to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work. You'll have to refactor. If you had used REST API you wouldn't have to refactor much, just your authentication, but JSOM will only function inside a SharePoint context.